# Change Div on hover of imagemap

Tags: jquery, html

Im trying to make a div appear when the user hovers over a part of an image map, ive searched around and found an example using jQuery however i cannot get it to work for the life of me.

Here is the code i currently have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Interactive Map - Test</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>




  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

  <style type='text/css'>
    .hidden {
    display: none;
}

  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$("area").hover(function () {
    $place = $(this).attr("alt");
    $(".place-default > div").addClass("hidden");
    $($place).removeClass("hidden");
}, function(){
    $(".place-default > div").addClass("hidden");
    $("#place-1").removeClass("hidden");
});

});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
                <div class="place-default">
                    <div class="default" id="place-1">
                        <ul>
                            <h2 style="width: 431px">
                                Geographically Broken Down
                            </h2>
                            <p>
                                North East
                                <br>
                                Yorkshire and the Humber
                                <br>
                                North West
                                <br>
                                West Midlands
                                <br>
                                East Midlands
                                <br>
                                East of England
                                <br>
                                London
                                <br>
                                South East
                                <br>
                                South West
                            </p>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hidden" id="place-2">
                        <ul>
                            <h2 style="width: 431px">
                                North East
                            </h2>
                            <p>
                                Durham
                                <br>
                                Northumberland
                                <br>
                                Redcar and Cleveland
                                <br>
                                Tyne and Wear
                            </p>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hidden" id="place-3">
                        <ul>
                            <h2 style="width: 431px">
                                Yorkshire and the Humber
                            </h2>
                            <p>
                                East Riding of Yorkshire
                                <br>
                                North Lincolnshire
                                <br>
                                North Yorkshire
                                <br>
                                South Yorkshire
                                <br>
                                West Yorkshire
                            </p>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hidden" id="place-4">
                        <ul>
                            <h2 style="width: 431px">
                                North West
                            </h2>
                            <p>
                                Cheshire
                                <br>
                                Cumbria
                                <br>
                                Greater Manchester
                                <br>
                                Lancashire
                                <br>
                                Merseyside
                            </p>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hidden" id="place-5">
                        <ul>
                            <h2 style="width: 431px">
                                West Midlands
                            </h2>
                            <p>
                                Herefordshire
                                <br>
                                Shropshire
                                <br>
                                Staffordshire
                                <br>
                                Warwickshire
                                <br>
                                West Midlands
                                <br>
                                Worcestershire
                            </p>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hidden" id="place-6">
                        <ul>
                            <h2 style="width: 431px">
                                East Midlands
                            </h2>
                            <p>
                                Derbyshire
                                <br>
                                Leicestershire
                                <br>
                                Lincolnshire
                                <br>
                                Northamptonshire
                                <br>
                                Nottinghamshire
                                <br>
                                Rutland
                            </p>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hidden" id="place-7">
                        <ul>
                            <h2 style="width: 431px">
                                East of England
                            </h2>
                            <p>
                                Bedfordshire
                                <br>
                                Cambridgeshire
                                <br>
                                Essex
                                <br>
                                Hertfordshire
                                <br>
                                Norfolk
                                <br>
                                Suffolk
                            </p>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hidden" id="place-8">
                        <ul>
                            <h2 style="width: 431px">
                                London
                            </h2>
                            <p>
                                Westminster
                                <br>
                                Canary Wharf
                                <br>
                                London City
                                <br>
                                Camden and Islington
                                <br>
                                Lambeth and Southwark
                            </p>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hidden" id="place-9">
                        <ul>
                            <h2 style="width: 431px">
                                South East
                            </h2>
                            <p>
                                Berkshire
                                <br>
                                Buckinghamshire
                                <br>
                                East Sussex
                                <br>
                                Isle of Wight
                                <br>
                                Kent
                                <br>
                                Oxfordshire
                                <br>
                                Surrey
                                <br>
                                West Sussex
                            </p>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hidden" id="place-10">
                        <ul>
                            <h2 style="width: 431px">
                                South West
                            </h2>
                            <p>
                                Bristol
                                <br>
                                Cornwall
                                <br>
                                Devon
                                <br>
                                Dorset
                                <br>
                                Gloucestershire
                                <br>
                                Isles of Scilly
                                <br>
                                Somerset
                                <br>
                                Wiltshire
                            </p>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="row"style="float: right">
                <div class="col-sm-6 block">
                    <div class="box">
                        <h2 style="width: 337px" class="text-right">Nationwide<br></h2>
            <img src="http://www.flash-map-shop.com/images/mapimages/EnglandRegion_Map.jpg" alt="" usemap="#Map" height="453" width="388" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area alt="place-10" title="SW" shape="poly" coords="212, 297, 168, 306, 143, 358, 83, 361, 12, 440, 36, 445, 111, 433, 173, 404, 203, 396, 217, 352"/>
    <area alt="place-9" title="SE"shape="poly" coords="214, 298, 258, 293, 268, 334, 275, 347, 291, 353, 304, 339, 324, 336, 343, 343, 359, 342, 361, 354, 336, 370, 324, 378, 310, 388, 307, 392, 275, 391, 249, 394, 222, 389, 210, 398"/>
    <area alt="place-8" title="LON" shape="poly" coords="272, 326, 289, 322, 301, 329, 295, 344, 287, 348, 276, 341, 270, 336"/>
    <area alt="place-7" title="EA" shape="poly" coords="258, 292, 300, 236, 352, 226, 368, 240, 363, 274, 348, 293, 334, 306, 324, 322, 319, 337, 284, 320, 269, 322"/>
    <area alt="place-5"shape="poly" title="WM" coords="143, 225, 195, 203, 219, 257, 226, 283, 182, 296, 153, 305, 145, 289"/>
    <area alt="place-6" title="EM" shape="poly" coords="197, 200, 198, 177, 212, 195, 233, 193, 246, 184, 275, 180, 288, 179, 297, 184, 300, 210, 292, 221, 291, 232, 295, 234, 291, 240, 247, 288, 231, 291"/>
    <area alt="place-3" title="YH" shape="poly" coords="183, 108, 255, 103, 293, 165, 281, 179, 245, 181, 232, 191, 216, 192, 200, 176, 191, 168, 185, 142, 174, 135, 173, 129, 171, 128"/>
    <area alt="place-2" title="place-2" shape="poly" coords="167, 48, 186, 27, 182, 7, 190, 3, 210, 19, 215, 51, 227, 88, 243, 96, 250, 100, 188, 106, 179, 85, 173, 76, 169, 77"/>
    <area alt="place-4" title="NW" shape="poly" coords="165, 49, 133, 74, 119, 101, 140, 128, 155, 127, 151, 155, 142, 189, 152, 209, 158, 215, 191, 201, 195, 177"/>
</map>

</div> 
</div>
</div>


</body>


</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Many Thanks crackruckles

Comment: You got an error in your javascript: change "$" to "jQuery" and the "hover" event works.

Comment: ok ive tried 

 <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
jQuery(window).load(function(){
jQuery("area").hover(function () {
    var place = jQuery(this).attr("href");
    jQuery(".place-default > div").addClass("hidden");
    jQuery(place).removeClass("hidden");
}, function(){
    jQuery(".place-default > div").addClass("hidden");
    jQuery("#place-1").removeClass("hidden");
});
});//]]>  
</script>

and i still cant get it to work, would you mind posting code?

Comment: Forgot something: change "jQuery(jQueryplace).removeClass("hidden");" to "jQuery('#'+jQueryplace).removeClass("hidden");"

Comment: Thank you so much, i managed to get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @grow got there first in the comments but here's the answer as an answer. Change the jquery selector to "#" + $place (I've renamed place without the $)

```
$("area").hover(function () {
    place = $(this).attr("alt");
    $(".place-default > div").addClass("hidden");
    $('#'+place).removeClass("hidden");
}, function(){
    $(".place-default > div").addClass("hidden");
    $("#place-1").removeClass("hidden");
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dq023ga7/